# Angular - ng-class working on td but not on tr

Tags: html, css, angularjs, html-table

The following HTML is used inside a ng-repeat.

This works:

```
<tr>
    <td ng-class="info.lastInMonth">{{ info.date_formatted }}</td>
    ...
```

But this doesn't work:

```
<tr ng-class="info.lastInMonth">
    <td>{{ info.date_formatted }}</td>
    ...
```

The exact same expression works in the td but not on the tr.

Anybody got an idea why?

Comment: info.lastInMonth is class name and from API call?

Comment: Yes exactly. Actually, it is empty most of the iterations. Only for the line that shows the latest data for one month, I want a special class to have CSS show a border on that <tr> element. The JSON from the API has that data only when that row is the last of the month. The data is fine (it works perfectly in the <td> and as well if I simply put it like this {{info.date_formatted}} {{info.lastInMonth}} ).... so the data that's coming from the API does not seem to be the problem as far as I can see.

Comment: Oh man, I have to say I stink (and I am overworked). I simply made the mistake that the ng-repeat element was a <tr> element and in my .html template file I had another <tr> element. Probably the browser just killed the double <tr> element (which could have had the ng-class). I now added the ng-class to the <tr> element that has the ng-repeat (and removed the double) and it works just fine... D'oh! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the styling is specific to `td`, it is safer to have them with `td`. Because `td` overrides the styling applied to `tr`.

Consider below `css` class:

```
.test{
    background: #ccddee;
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid #5a5a5a 5px;
}
```

Now apply this to `tr`

```
<table>
        <tr class="test"><td>cell content</td></tr>
    </table>
```

will produce output like, no border and padding applied :
[image]

If you apply the same to `td`

```
<table>
  <tr><td  class="test">cell content</td></tr>
</table>
```

you can see the borders and padding applied: [image]

Comment: Hi,Sridhar, thanks for your answer. I specifically want the class on the <tr> and not on the <td>.

Comment: Oh man, I have to say I stink (and I am overworked). I simply made the mistake that the ng-repeat element was a <tr> element and in my .html template file I had another <tr> element. Probably the browser just killed the double <tr> element (which could have had the ng-class). I now added the ng-class to the <tr> element that has the ng-repeat (and removed the double) and it works just fine... D'oh! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It actually works in my code. Try to find the differece between them. By the way , it can be caused by the edition of angular.

```js
var meadow = angular.module('meadow', []);
meadow = meadow.controller("abc", function($scope) {
  $scope.info = {
    lastInMonth: "a",
    date_formatted: "b"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="meadow" ng-controller="abc">
  <table>
    <tr ng-class="info.lastInMonth">
      <td>{{ info.date_formatted }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi @blackmiaool, thanks for taking the time. I was using 1.4.0. Just upgraded to 1.5.11 (last stable I found) but same problem. Can't make sense of it...

Comment: Oh man, I have to say I stink (and I am overworked). I simply made the mistake that the ng-repeat element was a <tr> element and in my .html template file I had another <tr> element. Probably the browser just killed the double <tr> element (which could have had the ng-class). I now added the ng-class to the <tr> element that has the ng-repeat (and removed the double) and it works just fine... D'oh! Thanks!